# Create database firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to create a firebase database separate for each user.

I have seen that I need to declare:

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference(**REF**);
```

What is the **REF** though?

Comment: One database per user is not really a good design. You can limit data a user "has access to" by appending the user ID to each related record, then you can filter by that

Answer (score 1):

By default, `database.getReference()` gives you the default `DatabaseReference` of the default path.

`database.getReference(**REF**)` gets a DatabaseReference for the provided path.

Acc. to Firebase Official Docs

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A DatabaseReference is a local reference (think: a pointer) to a location in your database.

When you run this:

```
DatabaseReference rootReference = database.getReference();
```

You get a reference to the root of your database:

```
/ <root>
```

From that root you can get references to child nodes in your database:

```
DatabaseReference usersRef = rootReference.child("users");
```

Now `usersRef` points to:

```
/ <root>
    users
```

You can even specify a complete path when calling `child()` to get a pointer to anywhere in your database/tree:

```
DatabaseReference myProfilePicRef = rootRef.child("users/myuid/avatarURL");
```

And `myProfilePicRef` will refer to this URL

```
/ <root>
    users
        myuid
            avatarURL: "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/12d378e6a9788ab9c94bbafe242b82b4?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG"
```

Finally to get to the code in your question: you can specify the path that you want to refer to straight away when you call get `getReference`. So these will result in reference to the same locations as before:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = database.getReference();
DatabaseReference usersRef = database.getReference("users");
DatabaseReference myProfilePicRefRef = database.getReference("users/myuid/avatarURL");
```